# Как получать, сортировать записи с БД по рейтингу?

Tags: python, sqlite

есть таблицы 'Content' и 'Rettig_Content',
в первой хранятся записи , а второй оценка этих записей,
нужно сделать рейтинг, чтобы сортировать и выводить первые записи с наибольшим рейтингом - это сумма / количество

```
Tabls:
Content:
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|----------|
      id  |   title   |    description   |  img   | datetime |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|----------|
      1   |    TEXT   |      TEXT        |  TEXT  | DATETIME |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|----------|
      2   |    TEXT   |      TEXT        |  TEXT  | DATETIME |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|----------|
      3   |    TEXT   |      TEXT        |  TEXT  | DATETIME |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|----------|



Rettig_Content:

    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|
      id  |  user_id  |    content_id    | voice  |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|
      1   |  44566    |      1           |  5     |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|
      2   |  23566    |      1           |  3     |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|
      3   |  55566    |      1           |  3     |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|
      4   |  44566    |      3           |  5     |
    ------|-----------|------------------|--------|
```

Comment: думаю стоит указать что значить с "наибольшим рейтингом"? сортировать по среднему рейтингу( среднее арифметическое)? или еще что то?

Comment: да, среднее арифметическое

Answer (score 2):

```
select c.id,c.title,c.description,c.img,c.datetime, avg(r.voice) as rate
  from Content as c
  left join Rettig_Content as r
    on r.content_id=c.id
 group by c.id,c.title,c.description,c.img,c.datetime
 order by rate desc
```